# Error occured while running JSP code

Tags: jsp

I cannot run my JSP code suddenly. It work normally at this morning but now it keeps showing me a sentences,

> The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details.

How can I solve this question?

Comment: Need more information like what is the server and version.

Comment: @raymond_wmt Please print the complete stacktrace

Comment: I think my glassfish server can not started. But I do not know how to restart it back.

Comment: I am using netbean IDE with glassfish server now. I can view my server in the services/ server tab but How can I restart my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error will occur mostly if you have removed some classes from the Application but they are still declared in the `web.xml` file. Please check that your `web.xml` file is correct.

Right Click on your xml file in netbeans and select validate and you will find out that something invalid is there. Either you have deleted or renamed some servlets in the Application.

I hope this helps.